# Does sharepoint designer 2013 requires SP server or SP foundation ..?

Tags: sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-online, office-365

I am running a site on office 365 online and can't install SP server or foundation on my personal computer due to its extensive hardware requirements. But I just need to use SP designer to modify master pages and styles sheet.

So, is that possible to install SP designer without having SP server installed..?

PS:
this is a public facing site

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SharePoint Designer is a Client tool so it doesn't require that SharePoint is installed on the machine only that you have access (and permissions) on the SharePoint site you want to inspect/modify.

But note that SharePoint Designer isn't the best tool to modify SharePoint 2013 master pages as it doesn't have Design view anymore. In fact any web design tool is probably better.

The way master pages are developed in SharePoint 2013 is by modifying .html pages which are stored in the Master Page Gallery `https://mysitename-public.sharepoint.com/_catalogs/masterpage`. See MSDN article [Develop the site design in SharePoint 2013](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj733518.aspx)

Comment: 'any web design tool'..? what other free tools I can use for designing my public facing site hosted on office 365..?

Comment: Can I edit HTML of master pages in this..? I have good knowledge of HTML and CSS. I can't find any option to edit my master page online from office 365 web interface.

Comment: See expanded answer